# how to add labels to btn-group-vertical?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-group

I created a very simple radio buttons using "btn-group-vertical".

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span> Private
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"><span class="fa fa-unlock"></span> Public
    </label>
</div>
```

[image]

But I couldn't find a simple way to add some label to the right of each button (like with standard radio buttons).

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to add some more explanation for each button/state

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. btn-group and btn-group-vertical bind a specific group of elements to construct a structure (vertical button). Adding extra html elements will break this structure.

I think finding an alternative will be the best to do for you. Consider using tooltips (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-container="body" title="tooltip on first input!" class="btn btn-primary">
        <input  type="radio" name="options" id="option1"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span> Private
    </label>
    <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-container="body" title="tooltip on second input!" class="btn btn-primary">
        <input  type="radio" name="options" id="option2"><span class="fa fa-unlock"></span> Public
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but that is not the design I like, I think it's better for the UX to see more details, without the need to hover.